# Error logging mysql, best practice

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I got a "big" Facebook-application coming up. It is programmed in php using mysql (and the mysql_-class, not PDO...I know, I know). As I am close to an open beta, I'd like to keep track of any mysql-errors. I have a good host and I know that the script never looses connection to the database, so I thought I could store this in a table.

I'd like to keep track of the query doing failing (not a problem), but I'd also like to know what line and file this happened in. I've seen `__LINE__` in a few scripts, but I never figured out how to use it.

My base simply looks like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * ...';
$result = mysql_do_query($query);

function mysql_do_query ($q) {
    [...]
}
```

My real question is; is it possible to log where the function `mysql_do_query` was called from? What line etc. Or is there another way to do this? Try and exceptions, perhaps?

Comment: Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Comment: `know that the script never looses connection to the database` ... I STRONGLY disagree with this

Comment: Well, I've been developing this project on my own for a two year period, my host is highly reliable and the only problems I've ever seen is my queries failing because results are not as expected. I could simply use a text-file and save it there, but I'd like to have more monitoring-options. So "never" is perhaps wrong, but I think 99,9% of all errors is caused by me and my programming. (@ajreal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), or [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php), or write your own error handler.

Comment: magic constants seems like the way to go, but if I use `__LINE__` etc inside my function, will it show me the line in the function, or where the function was called? I assume I have to place the LINE-part as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger_error(mysql_error()." $q");
```