# How to track error if data type mismatch during insert and update query in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have created table in mysql database. In that table I have one column with int(50) datatype. When I insert a new row that contain string value for that column, its going to stored as 0 (zero).

But i wants to track this error and appropriate data should be store in table.

Thanks..

Comment: You can use magic constants, or debug_backtrace, or write your own error handler. please check below link [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342491/error-logging-mysql-best-practice)

Comment: This is a simple insert query and nothing else like.....$query = "insert into table(id)values('test1')";   $result = $mysqli_test->query($query);  if(!$result){echo "ERROR while insert";}

Answer (score 0):

```
You can catch it via PDOException 

get the corresponding error code and handle it accordingly 

try { 
   // your code
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    // $e->getCode() will give you the error code corresponding
    // handle the exception accordingly 

}
```

If you just want the data to be inserted then you can go for 
INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl
then datatype mismatches are simply ignored

Comment: But i am using simple mysqli() to connect database and not used PDO so can this possible in my way of coding?Or pdo must?